# Mikrotik NAT works on RDP but not on ports 5555 or 8787

Tags: nat, mikrotik

I Have a router with some simple NAT rule that allowed me to remotelly connect to my remote desktop (now disabled), the problem is that the NAT does not work on ports 5555 and 8787 with similar configuration, see my config bellow.

```
[admin@MikroTik] > ip firewall nat print 
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 0    ;;; Remote Desktop
  chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.210 to-ports=3389 protocol=tcp 
  in-interface=ether1-WAN dst-port=3389 log=yes log-prefix="RDP->" 

  1    ;;; SDR
  chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.230 to-ports=5555 protocol=tcp 
  in-interface=ether1-WAN dst-port=5555 log=yes log-prefix="SDR->" 

  2    ;;; R Studio
  chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.222 to-ports=8787 protocol=udp 
  in-interface=ether1-WAN dst-port=8787 log=yes log-prefix="" 

  3    ;;; defconf: masquerade
  chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=WAN log=no log-prefix="MASK ->" 
  ipsec-policy=out,none
```

Thanks

Comment: If the RDP rule worked fine there is no reason for the other 2 not to work. Make sure you problem is not somewhere else (local firewall, local services).

Comment: Check the rule counters. Then check the filter rules. Then run the packet sniffer and capture the traffice. Then run the wireshark on the end host (where services run). Likely at one of these steps you will locate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a Internet router restart.